# Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag::get() must be of the type string, null given

Tags: php, laravel, symfony-http-foundation

> Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag::get() must be of the type string, null given, called in D:\Syed Ghazanfar\Futafut\Backend\v2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php on line 157

I got an error when I update my laravel version from 5.8 to 7.29, this error is showing only my web.php route,my api routes working fine, I have followed laravel upgrade guide also, I have tried to comment all my web routes, I have tried also `php artisan optimize:clear`, I have create one route and call its call back function and return 1 but still same error.

Here is error;

[image]

Here is RouteServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you opened a issue on Laravel repository as suggested in the symfony repo? Likely seems to be a laravel bug.

Comment: yes I have raise this question in symfony but they told me this issue is created from laravel

Comment: What does laravel say?

Comment: Basically we are moving our laravel version from 5.8 to 8, during the migration of this version laravel pass this exception.